# If I implement a load balanced to have my domain. how do i block the automatically generated url for my api gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-api-gateway, google-cloud-armor

I am implementing security to my Cloud Run services through an Api Gateway NEG and a load balanced
I need block the automatically generated url for my api gateway so that they only access my services through the load balanced

From what I understand Cloud Armor can only be used with the load balancer and not directly with the APi gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ingress for your services to "Internal and Load Balancing only". You can do this in the Google Console:
[image]

Or, if you use Terraform by adding:

```
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      "run.googleapis.com/ingress" = "internal-and-cloud-load-balancing"
    }

  }
```

to the top level in your terraform resource.

Comment: Of course, but the issue is that I have an Api Gateway that contains my routes from my Cloud Runs.
I do not have my load balancer configured with a Cloud run NEG but with an api gateway one.
What I want to block is the autogenerated url for the api-gateway.